# What should I do if one leg of my travel plan is cancelled by the airline?

Tags: air-travel, transit, bookings, italy, cancellations

I have following legs of flight travel I have to cover in December:

- Delhi to Milan (MXP), Air Italy, dep. Monday 6am India time
- Milan to Rome (FCO), Air Italy, dep. Monday 5pm Italy time
- Rome to Athens (ATH), Ryanair, dep. Tuesday 10am Italy time

First two are under ONE TICKET. There's a similar return route while returning as well.

Air Italia sent me an email today telling that the **DEL>MXP** flight on Monday has been cancelled. They are offering the same flight **next day** but with that, I will miss **Rome>ATH** flight despite keeping original time margin of over 14 hours. The flight is non-refundable.

What should I do to ensure that:

1. I don't lose money because I booked flights with an airline that is losing money
2. I don't miss visiting beautiful ancient cities of Europe

Comment: You may try explaining your situation and asking them to book you to Athens.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once.

Answer (score 3):

Since your original flight was cancelled and rescheduled, you could ask the airline to refund your ticket price, and then you could find a different flight (on the same or a different airline) to Rome that allows you to meet your connection. You could also ask the airline if they would move you to a flight on the previous day, which would allow you to meet your connection and also give you an extra day in Rome.

Comment: I had booked the flight well in advance - and right now prices are almost 1.5 times of what I paid. Maybe I'll request them to arrange flight for previous day.