# Is travel insurance valid if the flight dates got rescheduled by the Airline?

Tags: schengen, italy, insurance, cancellations

AirItaly has some changes in their flight schedule and [broke my itinerary](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123299/what-should-i-do-if-one-leg-of-my-travel-plan-is-cancelled-by-the-airline) which might already make me pay a lot to schedule other flights in my journey and spend money on hotels etc.

But with regard to this question, say, my original stay in Italy and Athens falls between December 1 to December 20, and my travel insurance is valid during these dates. But their schedule change might make my stay fall between November 30 to December 21.

Now I'm yet to apply for Schengen visa too.

Would such a flight change be an issue during visa application and immigration?

Would flight company (AirItaly) offer any assistance in this regard?

Answer (score 3):

The one and only source of an answer for this question is your Insurance Policy itself.  Either read the policy, and/or contact the insurance company to confirm whether you are covered, and/or how you can change your coverage dates.

Some policies will automatically extend the policy validity if the trip is extended by an event that is covered by the policy.  So if a flight is cancelled and have to stay an additional day then you may be covered - however even if your policy does have such a provision it's possible that a schedule change in advance may not be covered by it.

Travel Insurance terms and conditions vary wildly between companies and even specific policies, so only the T&C's themselves or the company can help you.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is to just get the travel insurance for more days than the originally scheduled trip. For example, if you're traveling from Dec 1st to Dec 31st, get an insurance covering Nov 25th to Jan 5th. This way you're covered if something goes wrong on either side of your trip. Given that travel insurance is usually very cheap, padding it with a few extra days usually won't make a dent in your budget, especially compared to the price of the ticket itself.

The same issue arises all the time with things other than travel insurance: visas, hotel bookings, car rentals, important business meetings, etc. And the solution is always the same - give yourself some breathing room rather than relying on everything going perfectly according to plan.

Answer (score -1):

On the MAWISTA Visum Comfort that I have bought for my Schengen trip in Dec 2018, following has been indicated:

"*For the insured person from visa requiring countries: Your insurance cover is valid within the period starting from 04.12.2018 until 03.12.2019 for multiple stays within the policy territory up to 8 days.
Multiple reentries and departures are possible. The duration of stay(s)
will be proven by the re-entry and departure stamps in the passport of the insured person.*"

I am not sure if you have the same insurance, but check for something similar mentioned on your insurance document, and if so, it should be valid provided you enter on or after the inception date (4th Dec for me) for upto a year..

Comment: That clause does not answer the question. It only says that the stamps serve as proof of the travel dates, not if you are covered.

Comment: I think it does. And what it says is you are allowed to enter for a period of 8 days on or after the inception date. For the OP, entering the day before the inception may cause an issue with regards to the insurance, in that, he may not be covered on Nov 30th. But if his insurance is valid for number of days of journey (including the changed dates), the dates of entry and exit dont matter as long as they fall within a one year period from the inception date and that the stamps on passport will indicate the actual entry and exit dates.

Comment: Whether the OP's insurance will cover changed dates will be controlled by the terms of that insurance. In any event, I'd bet dollars to donuts that the airline's T&Cs will absolve the airline of this consequential liability.

Comment: What is *MAWISTA Visum Comfort*? Is that (can that be) relevant to the OP?

Comment: Yes @jan-doggen, it is the travel insurance that is recommended by Schengen member states. Please check https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-insurance/

Comment: @Bhushan Kale I believe the official site is https://www.schengen-visa-info.eu/ The site your comment links to is a commercial organisation (.eu versus .com)

Comment: Wow thanks, this website never showed up on my google searches.

Comment: @Traveller schengen-visa-info.eu is also not an official site. Anybody can register a .eu domain, including commercial organizations. There is no specific travel insurance company recommended by Schengen member states, just requirements that a policy must satisfy.

Comment: @Zach Lipton Thanks, I realised Schengen members states would be highly unlikely to recommend a specific travel insurance, but I had thought the .eu site was official. Just shows how careful one needs to be :-)

Comment: @Traveller that is what I thought with the .com site and was surprised to see them recommend anything.